# Create mocks in api functional testing with Symfony

Tags: api, symfony, mocking, functional-testing

I'm dealing with a problem I have in a Symfony 4 API functional tests. My functional tests consists in making requests to the API and analyze the response given. I've been working like this and works fine.

The problem comes with a new API method I'm implementing which needs the perform a request to an external service. I want to mock during my tests, but I don't know how can I create a mock that persists when the API receives the request from the functional test.

I've been thinking about something like create mocks which are always used in the test environment but I haven't found anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check in http-client service called url and if it compare your external api url return certain response, it will be look something like this:

```
$guzzleServiceMock = $this
->getMockBuilder(GuzzleHttp\Client::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()
->setMethods(['get'])
->getMock();

$guzzleServiceMock
    ->expects($this->any())
    ->method('get')
    ->with(
        $this->stringContains('/external/api/route')
    )
    ->willReturnCallback(
        function ($uri, $options = []) {
            return new Response(
                200,
                [],
                '{"result": {
                    "status": "success",
                    "data": "fake data",
                }}'
            );
        }
    );
```

next step you will need to inject service into container, with this question you can look this repo, there are good examples of how this can be done: https://github.com/peakle/symfony-4-service-mock-examples/blob/master/tests/Util/BaseServiceTest.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but if you'd like to mock an external API (meaning your application is connecting to another application on another server), one solution would be to actually lunch a mock server to replace your actual external server.

Either you implement such a mock server yourself or you use an existing solution such as http://wiremock.org/

Comment: The problem is that I'm not testing an external API. I want to test the API which I'm currently developing but in functional tests I'm performing real requests to the API, so I don't know how to create a specific mock for a method called in my API.

Comment: @Carles If you're calling the API via `client->request()`, then there's nothing you can mock. You would have to make it a unit test.